# Should we allow or disallow tags for future releases?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I saw some tag wiki suggestions for [battlefield-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-4) in the review queue today. The game doesn't come out for several months and so has no valid questions until that time, so why do we need such a tag right now? Should tag wikis for upcoming games be rejected (if they're not coming out in a few days)?

Comment: The tag will be automatically deleted for not having any questions tagged with it

Comment: Someone asked a Battlefield 4 question earlier today, but later deleted their question.

Comment: Grats about 5,000 reps!

Comment: @jmfsg Please convert that to an answer :).

Comment: @deutschZuid it doesn't really answer the question, it's more of a "don't worry about it" kind of thing

Comment: I've asked the question and corresponding tag. Here is meta question related to that: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/what-is-considered-future-here

Comment: It's possibly a whole different can of worms - but I'll add to this discussion that I think our policies on Betas are in conflict with the "no speculation on future releases".  The fear about future releases is that we might have a sourced answer which turns out to be wrong when the game is released.  But the same thing can happen with a Beta - and for that matter, the same thing can and does happen with post-release patches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We shouldn't have tags for games that we can't have questions about.

Fortunately, the system handles this for us, once the (off topic!) question on which the tag was used is suitably and swiftly deleted, the tag will be purged from the system within the next day.

If someone is foolish enough to try to submit a wiki for such a tag, feel free to reject it as not helpful or with a custom reject explaining that the tag is slated for deletion. It happens often enough.

Answer (score -5):

Just because a game isn't out doesn't mean you can't have a question about it, does it?

- Will Battlefield 4 on the Xbox support 64 players?

  - [Yes](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/articles/18200/20130610/battlefield-4-release-date-bringing-naval-combat.htm)
- Will BF4 be relased on the Xbox 360 or Xbox One?

  - [Both](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/buy)
- etc...

I think these are good examples of completely valid and potentially answerable questions.

Comment: These are *exactly* the types of questions we do NOT want.  This is why questions about unreleased games are **off-topic**.

Comment: Why do "we" NOT want these?

Comment: @ScottBeeson We've had a long history of discussion on the subject; you're welcome to look around here on Meta and find the old posts. The conclusion we came to is that we don't do questions about unreleased games.

Comment: @ScottBeeson: Speculation about future releases are off-topic for a number of reasons. First, there's no way to answer a question until it's released. Games change all the time in developments, and features are added and removed frequently. Second, many of these questions are completely irrelevant once the game is released. Third, you're supposed to only ask questions about "problems you actually face." Whether or not a game has a feature before it's released is not a problem that you actually face. For all these reasons questions about future released are almost always closed as off-topic.

Comment: Well, saying there's "no way to answer a question until it's released" is just silly (see examples) and I think this is doing a major disservice to the community.  But if that's what the regime decided on, so be it I guess...

Comment: History is *littered* with broken promises from game developers.  Molyneux is a prime example of over-promising and under-delivering.  That's a perfect example of official information **being wrong**.  It's part of the reasons why we don't allow these questions.  As a sidenote, calling us a regime is at least slightly annoying.  If you want to be constructive, I'd recommend toning down the attitude.

Comment: Well in fairness your first response had italics, caps and bold, but I digress.

Comment: Italics, caps, and bold? How dare you, @fbueckert!

Comment: lol +1 for SaintWacko

Comment: Sorry; I tend to get passionate about this.  Much of it is that there's lots of history behind why we don't allow it, and it's all available on meta to read, so I'm not a fan of people going, "Nothing wrong with this!", and not knowing the history behind it.  I apologize.

Comment: Fair enough, but you can't expect the average user wanting to know "What platforms will Battlefield 4 be released on" to read the entire contents of meta to understand why their perfectly reasonable question is invalid.

Comment: @ScottBeeson No, but we can expect them to type their question into google first. Part of the tooltip on the downvote arrow is 'shows poor research effort'.

Comment: People are expected to read the FAQ and rules on every forum i have ever been. And thus people are expected to know the rules and guidelines of those forums and websites. Stackexchange is not any different, just a bit more strict on the rules to keep things tidy.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: if you'd eliminate questions that show "poor research effort", you'd be left with nothing, as most questions here can be answered just by going to *<name_of_the_game>*.wikia.com

Comment: @vartec [We discussed our site's role and what we can offer early on in our site's inception](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/1007/160). Just because other resources exist, it doesn't mean we don't have anything to bring to the table.

Comment: @FAE: I'm not convinced. Wikia sites are usually quite refined and crystallized. And unlike answers here, wikia sites are usually updated. So does failing to google wikia "show a poor research effort"?

Comment: @vartec If you don't think this site is useful and distinct in it's role, you're welcome to leave. Being an Arqade user is not a mandatory activity.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: that's the spirit, keep up the good job...

Comment: Wiki sites take time to get off the ground and organized.  Arqade *excels* at having boots on the ground and getting answers rolling while people are still deciding on wiki layouts, let alone actually providing information.  We also excel at providing *specific* information tailored to the exact problem presented, rather than general information like wikis do.

Comment: Those sorts of questions can easily be found with a Google or Wikipedia search, and are irrelevant once the game releases.

Comment: If a game has not been released, there whont be any factual content. Therefore any answeres regarding none-released games would be based on "what to expect" and NOT on facts. All gamecreaters have the possiblity to change content up and till the release. All questions would proberbly be valid, but all answers would be blurry.